# Samsung Android phone / tablet drivers without using the Samsung Kies

Tags: samsung-kies

As Samsung Kies require one to be online in order to install but all I need are just Samsung drivers so that the OS (e.g. Windows XP, Windows 7) can recognize the Samsung Android device.

So, how to connect the Samsung Android phone / tablet to the PC without using Samsung Kies so that the OS can recognize that the Samsung Android device?

Similarly, how do one install Samsung Kies without connecting to the Internet? This is because sometime, one need to access the android device on PC which does not have Internet access or in an restricted area.

Comment: What device do you have?  Some have driver packages available separately from Kies.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into SideSync for Samsung devices? I use it instead of Kies now and love it

http://www.samsung.com/us/sidesync/

Sidesync has a lot of great features:

- Display your phone or table from your PC and control it.
- Send and receive phone calls from your laptop
- Access all of your apps (like sending/reading SMS messages)
- See notifications from your device on your PC
- Access your Phone/Tablet via USB or wireless on the same network
- Drag and drop files to and from device

Answer (score 0):

1wayjonny on XDA has released a [Naked Driver](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1161769) for some Samsung devices. The driver itself will let your PC recognize your phone in ADB, FB or APX mode.